# Modify footer in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, footer

is there a way to put an external link on MediaWiki's footer?
I've tried to add in my localsetting.php this code:

```
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec'][] = function( $sk, &$tpl ) {

  $tpl->set( 'aboutus', $sk->footerLink( 'aboutus', 'aboutuspage' ) );
  // or to add non-link text:
  $tpl->set( 'footertext', 'Text to show in footer' );
  $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'aboutus';
  return true;
};
```

But this go to create a Mediawiki's page, and i want to add a link to a contact page. I've modified the MediaWiki:Aboutus and MediaWiki:Aboutuspage pages, but nothing, continue to remind me to a MediaWiki's page.

Answer (score 1):

What do you put in "MediaWiki:Aboutus"? You've to actually create the html link.
Try this

```php
  $wgHooks['SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec'][] = function( $sk, &$tpl ) {
            $aboutusLink = Html::element( 'a', [ 'href' => $sk->msg( 'aboutus-url' )->escaped() ],
            $sk->msg( 'aboutus-label' )->text() ) ;
      $tpl->set( 'aboutus', $aboutusLink );
      $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'aboutus';
      return true;
  };
```

Then on your wiki create the page "MediaWiki:Aboutus-url" and directly place the external link you want you use. Also create the page "MediaWiki:Aboutus-label" and place the text to show on the surface. This allows you to change the url and label by modifying that wiki page messages any time, just as it seems you wanted to do so. If you want to hardcode everything in LocalSettings.php however, then use this:

```php
$wgHooks['SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec'][] = function( $sk, &$tpl ) {
        $aboutusLink = Html::rawelement( 'a', [ 'href' => 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427663/modify-footer-in-mediawiki' ],
        'Text to show as label' );
    $tpl->set( 'aboutus', $aboutusLink );
    $tpl->data['footerlinks']['places'][] = 'aboutus';
    return true;
};
```

Comment: It works the first code! Thank you so much, you've saved me!

Comment: `SkinTemplateOutputPageBeforeExec` was removed in version 1.37.0